# how to design change in woocommerce cart page and all other page also by theme?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, themes

I want to change all woocommerce pages design change as per my theme template so what can i do .

Comment: is it possible or not ?

Comment: The first you can do: search. The next thing: read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. To override WooCommerce template files in your theme (or child theme) simply make a folder named `woocommerce` within your theme directory, and then create the folders/template file you wish to override within it. 
This link **[overriding templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)** is having the procedure to override templates via a theme.